# Order the execution of taskgroups in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I'm looking for a way to choose the execution order of task groups in Airflow.
With the script below, the pipeline is running horizontal indeed it runs the task `call_first_task_US` then `call_first_task_FR`. However, I want it to be vertical meaning that it would run the task `call_first_task_US` then `call_second_task_US` before running the whole tasks of `workflow_FR`.

How should I proceed to order the workflow run ?

[image]

```
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from pendulum import datetime
import time


def first_task(country_id: str):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"country = {country_id}")


def second_task(country_id: str):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"country = {country_id}")


default_args = {
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 10, 8)
}

with DAG(
        dag_id="my_dag",
        concurrency=1,
        schedule_interval='0 0 12 * *',
        default_args=default_args
) as dag:

    start_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start',
    )

    end_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end',
    )

    for country in ["US", "FR"]:
        with TaskGroup(group_id=f"workflow_{country}") as workflow:
            call_first_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f"call_first_task_{country}",
                python_callable=first_task,
                op_kwargs={
                    "country_id": country
                }
            )

            call_second_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f"call_second_task_{country}",
                python_callable=second_task,
                op_kwargs={
                    "country_id": country
                }
            )

            start_task >> call_first_task >> call_second_task >> end_task
        start_task >> workflow
```

Comment: Why do you define them as parallel while you want them to be executed in sequence? Capture current start task as `start_task` before loop pass and update current start task at the end of loop pass setting it to `workflow`. Or, equivalently and more clear, preform reduction on a list providing `start_task` as a seed and returning generated task group on each reduction step as current value.

Comment: What Airflow version are you running?

Comment: I defined them as parallel because I believed that it was possible to execute them one by one in sequence. 
I wanna avoid a workflow blocking another because of failure.

The airflow version is 2.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to achieve this way, follow this code [image]

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from pendulum import datetime
import time


def first_task(country_id: str):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"country = {country_id}")


def second_task(country_id: str):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"country = {country_id}")


default_args = {
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 10, 8)
}

with DAG(
        dag_id="my_dag",
        concurrency=1,
        schedule_interval='0 0 12 * *',
        default_args=default_args
) as dag:

    start_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start',
    )

    end_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end',
    )

    with TaskGroup(group_id="workflow_US") as workflow_US:
        call_first_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="call_first_task_US",
            python_callable=first_task,
            op_kwargs={
                "country_id": "US"
            }
        )

        call_second_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="call_second_task_US",
            python_callable=second_task,
            op_kwargs={
                "country_id": "US"
            }
        )

    with TaskGroup(group_id="workflow_FR") as workflow_FR:
        call_first_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="call_first_task_FR",
            python_callable=first_task,
            op_kwargs={
                "country_id": "FR"
            }
        )

        call_second_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="call_second_task_US",
            python_callable=second_task,
            op_kwargs={
                "country_id": "FR"
            }
        )

    start_task >> workflow_US >> workflow_FR >> end_task
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
However I wanna keep the for loop to avoid writing the same code for each workflow. But I can see your point there.
By the way, If I have a list of countries such as ```countries = ["US", "FR", "SP", "BE"]``` Is there a way to dynamically order the workflow run with a list instead of writing in down like that ```start_task >> workflow_US >> workflow_FR >> end_task```?

Comment: As far as I know, TG with for loop can be created in vertical order but not in horizontal, this is the best practice

Comment: Alright ! Thanks for your input !